# Lein is not running my main method

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Lein is not running my main method. I've even introduced syntax errors, and it doesn't catch them. I'm really stumped. I'd greatly appreciate any assistance from the community.

I believe the main method is specified correctly. The first code sample is server.clj, with the main method. Next is my project.clj.

```
  (ns naac.server
  (:require [naac.handler :refer [handler]]
            [config.core :refer [env]]
            [migratus.core :as migratus]
            [ring.adapter.jetty :refer [run-jetty]]
            [naac.db :refer [load-db!]])
  (:gen-class))

(def db-config {:store :database
                :db (get (System/getenv) "DATABASE_URL"
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jeff")
                :migration-dir "migrations"})

 (defn -main [& args]
   (println args)
   (doseq [a args]
     (cond
       (= a "migrate")
         (do
           (println "Migrate database...")
           (migratus/migrate  db-config)
           (println "...Migration done."))
       (= a "rollback")
         (do
           (println "Rollback database...")
           (migratus/rollback db-config)
           (println "...Rollback done."))
       (= a "load")
         (do
           (println "Load database...")
           (load-db!)
           (println "...Load done."))))

  (if (> (count args) 0) (System/exit 0))

  (let [port (Integer/parseInt (or (env :port) "3000"))]
   (run-jetty handler {:port port :join? false})))
```

My project.clj:

```
 (defproject naac "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.229"]
                 [reagent "0.6.0"]
                 [re-frame "0.9.2"]
                 [compojure "1.5.0"]
                 [yogthos/config "0.8"]
                 [migratus "0.9.2"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                 [com.layerware/hugsql "0.4.7"]
                 [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4.1207"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.4"]
            [migratus-lein "0.4.1"]]

  :min-lein-version "2.5.3"

  :source-paths ["src"]

  :clean-targets ^{:protect false} ["resources/public/js/compiled" "target"]

  :figwheel {:css-dirs ["resources/public/css"]
             :ring-handler naac.handler/dev-handler}

  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[binaryage/devtools "0.8.2"]]
         :plugins      [[lein-figwheel "0.5.9"]]
         :resource-paths ["resources/config"]}
   }

  :migratus {:store :database
             :db ~(get (System/getenv) "DATABASE_URL"
                    "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jeff")
             :migration-dir "migrations"}

  :cljsbuild
  {:builds
   [{:id           "dev"
     :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
     :figwheel     {:on-jsload "naac.core/mount-root"}
     :compiler     {:main                 naac.core
                    :output-to            "resources/public/js/compiled/app.js"
                    :output-dir           "resources/public/js/compiled/out"
                    :asset-path           "js/compiled/out"
                    :source-map-timestamp true
                    :preloads             [devtools.preload]
                    :external-config      {:devtools/config {:features-to-install :all}}
                    }}

    {:id           "min"
     :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
     :jar true
     :compiler     {:main            naac.core
                    :output-to       "resources/public/js/compiled/app.js"
                    :optimizations   :advanced
                    :closure-defines {goog.DEBUG false}
                    :pretty-print    false}}


    ]}

  :main naac.server

  :aot [naac.server]

  :uberjar-name "naac.jar"

  :prep-tasks [["cljsbuild" "once" "min"] "compile"]
  )
```

MY directory structure can be seen in [this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6UKqYRvrAyUZWZLVXR0SHpXUEE/view?usp=sharing). IF you need a deeper nesting level you can see it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6UKqYRvrAyUUkxLb3dRemZlZHM).

When I run lein I get this output:

```
    Compiling ClojureScript...
2017-05-09 12:12:12.739:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2438ms
May 09, 2017 12:12:12 PM clojure.tools.logging$eval18$fn__22 invoke
INFO: Starting migrations
May 09, 2017 12:12:12 PM clojure.tools.logging$eval18$fn__22 invoke
WARNING: skipping: '.DS_Store' migrations must match pattern: ^(\d+)-([^\.]+)((?:\.[^\.]+)+)$
May 09, 2017 12:12:12 PM clojure.tools.logging$eval18$fn__22 invoke
INFO: Ending migrations
May 09, 2017 12:12:12 PM clojure.tools.logging$eval18$fn__22 invoke
INFO: Starting migrations
May 09, 2017 12:12:12 PM clojure.tools.logging$eval18$fn__22 invoke
WARNING: skipping: '.DS_Store' migrations must match pattern: ^(\d+)-([^\.]+)((?:\.[^\.]+)+)$
May 09, 2017 12:12:12 PM clojure.tools.logging$eval18$fn__22 invoke
INFO: Ending migrations
May 09, 2017 12:12:12 PM clojure.tools.logging$eval18$fn__22 invoke
INFO: Starting migrations
May 09, 2017 12:12:12 PM clojure.tools.logging$eval18$fn__22 invoke
WARNING: skipping: '.DS_Store' migrations must match pattern: ^(\d+)-([^\.]+)((?:\.[^\.]+)+)$
May 09, 2017 12:12:12 PM clojure.tools.logging$eval18$fn__22 invoke
INFO: Ending migrations
```

Comment: What are the paths of your files and what does `lein run` output?

Comment: Thank you for helping! Here's the tree structure. Yikes, I can't type it into the comment. Let me see if I can update my original post.

Comment: I linked to an image of the directory structure.

Comment: Try source-paths with ["src/clj"]

Comment: That seems to have worked! Thank you Alejandro! I'm new to StackOverflow. How do I upvote you, sir?

Comment: @Jeff He'd have to move this comment into an answer, for you to accept.

Comment: @Jeff moved to a proper answer for posterity. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `:source-paths` in your `project.clj`. Lein expects your namespace folder to be directly in the source path.

You can either move your `naac` folder directly into `src` (e.g. `src/naac/server.clj`) or use `["src/clj"]` as the value for `:source-paths`